# Change a section by clicking on a photo or post

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

Change a section by clicking on a photo or post.
I want when I click on a photo or text to scroll up and one section is hidden and another section is displayed. And when I click on another photo again, that section will be hidden and the information of another section will be displayed.
Like the team members of a company, when we click on each person, information about that person is displayed.
**my website is wordpress.**

```
enter <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9da4f1d matn elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="9da4f1d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">
            <p><span style="font-size: 10pt;">خستگی‌ناپذیر و در مسیر رشد؛ شوق یادگیری در DNA امین تنیده شده و برای همین همیشه در حال یادگیری و تمرین کردن هست. صبر مثال زدنی او، برای همه اعضای تیم باعث دلگرمی و آرامش هست و در برابر مشکلات پیش آمده، خم به ابروی خودش نمیاره. به کارگیری تجربه 11 ساله وی در زمینه ارسال پیام کوتاه، در کنار رعایت اصول اخلاقی و مشتری مداری ایده پردازان، و تیم پرانگیزه و با دانش این واحد، روند رو به رشد SMS.ir را تضمین می کند.</span></p>                  </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-7a8d85e elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-view-more" data-id="7a8d85e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-view-more.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div class="jet-view-more" data-settings="{&quot;effect&quot;:&quot;zoom-in&quot;,&quot;sections&quot;:{&quot;12a5ff6&quot;:&quot;11&quot;},&quot;showall&quot;:false}"><div class="jet-view-more__button"><div class="jet-view-more__label">مشاهده اعضای تیم</div></div></div>     </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
            <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-2b199f5" data-id="2b199f5" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-33d2410 22 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="33d2410" data-element_type="widget" id="22" data-widget_type="image.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <div class="elementor-image">
                                            <img width="1280" height="1280" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%201280%201280'%3E%3C/svg%3E" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="امین ربیعی" data-lazy-srcset="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee.jpg 1280w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-300x300.jpg 300w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-150x150.jpg 150w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-768x768.jpg 768w" data-lazy-sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px" data-lazy-src="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee.jpg" /><noscript><img width="1280" height="1280" src="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="امین ربیعی" srcset="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee.jpg 1280w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-300x300.jpg 300w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-150x150.jpg 150w, https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Mr-Amin-Rabiee-768x768.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px" /></noscript>                                                     </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8c7c812 elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-absolute elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="8c7c812" data-element_type="widget" data-settings="{&quot;_position&quot;:&quot;absolute&quot;}" data-widget_type="image.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <div class="elementor-image">
                                            <img width="276" height="260" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20276%20260'%3E%3C/svg%3E" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" data-lazy-src="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/team-background.png" /><noscript><img width="276" height="260" src="https://final.sms.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/team-background.png" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" /></noscript>                                                       </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
                            </div>
                </div>here
```

part 2 :

```
enter <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-a89ab0e elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="a89ab0e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="/author/s-malek/">ثمین ملک</a></h2>     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e3d006 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="4e3d006" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="/author/s-malek/">کارشناس پشتیبانی</a></h2>     </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>here
```

Comment: Please provide proper code of where you are stuck.

Comment: I edited the code above

Comment: The code of the first part is the display of complete information.
The code of the second part is the introduction of the company member. I want to click on its image or its title, I want to change the text of the above code completely along with its image

Comment: Is there an error or something you are receiving that is causing you a problem

Comment: no. i dont know.